# How to display human time (x days ago, or now) in django admin?

Tags: django, datetime, django-admin

How can I display time/date format used in facebook/twitter in django **admin**?

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class Course(models.Model):

      date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      description = models.TextField()

      def get_date(self):
          time = datetime.now()
          if self.date.day == time.day:
              return str(time.hour - self.date.hour) + " hours ago"
          else:
              if self.month == time.month:
                   return str(time.day - self.date.day) + " days ago"

          return self.date

      def __str__(self):
          return self.title
```

---

**Admin.py**

```
  from django.contrib import admin
  from .models import Course   

  @admin.register(Course)
  class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ('title', 'description', 'get_date',)
```

Tried a number of combination to import date/time but still get errors as shown in the image.
[image]

If I use the get_date: I get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/courses/course/
'Course' object has no attribute 'month'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/courses/course/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Course' object has no attribute 'month'
Exception Location: /courses/models.py in get_date, line 17
```

Expected result to display the created_at and updated_at in human time.
To show

- 2 days ago
- Now
- A few minutes ago

Expected result: 2 days ago, or 3 hours ago. or better yet, a few hours ago.

[image]

Comment: The django admin site is made out of templates, and you can [override or customize them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates)

Comment: I rather not change the admin template for this. I am trying to find out if there is a library I can import and do the format change.

Comment: @Stryker you solved this?

Comment: @FACode. Not really. Will you be able to give an example of how to use that in a django model. Like if I have the following, how can I show the date like 2days ago or a few minutes ago. class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use extra methods in your model like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_date(self):
        time = datetime.now()
        if self.created_at.day == time.day:
            return str(time.hour - self.created_at.hour) + " hours ago"
        else:
            if self.created_at.month == time.month:
                return str(time.day - self.created_at.day) + " days ago"
            else:
                if self.created_at.year == time.year:
                    return str(time.month - self.created_at.month) + " months ago"
        return self.created_at
```

or you can create some utils functions for do that and just use it in your model method if you want to use in more situations

Here is the documentation for Django admin, here you find all that you need:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: @Stryker This example doesn't help you?

Comment: This example works for me. If you want, you can create an more complex function for doing this.

Comment: I will try it again in a few hours. Perhaps I made a mistake.

Comment: Update your question with your admin.py file. You have not added the method in your list_display. You must replace your 'date' from list_display with get_date method

Comment: I updated my answer. Try now. Here was some copy-paste errors.

Comment: Displays -1 day ago. But good enough. I can work with that. Many thanks for your patience.

Comment: You can improve this function. Glad to help you. :)

Comment: This answer is not good at all. What about when you have the same dates for different years ? Sep 11, 1990 and Sep 13, 2022 will display [**2 days ago**] smh

Answer (score 46):

There is an accepted answer however I want to suggest another thing who came here for a solution which can be used in templates.

Django has a contrib package called `django.contrib.humanize`. Add this to your INSTALLED_APPS, then use `{% load humanize %}` in your template, after that, you can use `value|naturaltime` template tag. "value" will be your date.

Let's say `content.created`, which contains the creation date of your content. It's a datetimefield object. So, you can use this: `content.created|naturaltime`. It'll convert the date e.g from July 14, 2018 11:30 to "3 days 1 hour ago".

[Check it on Django DOCS.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime)

Answer (score 17):

Turns out the template filters can be accessed directly from your Python codebase. Something like this:

```py
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags import humanize

class Example(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_date(self):
        return humanize.naturaltime(self.date)
```

The `get_date()` function can also be located within your `CourseAdmin` class.

Answer (score 4):

**I found this useful**

use it in your template, eg. index.html

```
{{ post.timestamp | timesince }}
```