# how to get time since from datetime field

Tags: django, django-models

In Django templates, I can do time since on my model to get how long a post was made

Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    trade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

```
{{post.date_posted|timesince}}
```

The above would return me something like **1 day, 8 hours ago**

My question is how would I do it on my model itself?

So that the **date_posted** field returns it in the humanized format itself.

I tried adding the following to my model but it doesn't work

```
    def FORMAT(self):
       return timesince(self.date_posted)
```

I'd like to do this so that when I make an API call to the post using DRF it returns me time in a humanized form and I can inject it directly in my front end(Next.js).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display human time (x days ago, or now) in django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345450/how-to-display-human-time-x-days-ago-or-now-in-django-admin) I'll suggest you shold check this answer first https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905718/14457833

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`timesince.timesince(...)`** function directly as,

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timesince


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    trade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    @property
    def timesince(self):
        return timesince.timesince(self.date_posted)
```